# PHP mysqli Insert not working, but not giving any errors

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli

As the title says Im trying to do a simple insert, but nothing actually is inserted into the table. I try to print out errors, but nothing is reported.

My users table has many more fields than these 4, but they should all default.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (username, password, level, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
if($stmt = $db -> prepare($query))
{
    $stmt -> bind_param('ssis', $username, $password, $newlevel, $realname);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> close();
    echo 'Any Errors: '.$db->error.PHP_EOL;
}
```

There are no errors given, but when I go to look at the table in phpmyadmin there is not a new row added. I know for sure that the types are correct (strings and integers). Is there something really wrong here or does it have something to do with the fact that I'm ignoring other columns. I have about 8 columns in the user table.

Comment: have you checked to make sure that you're actually connected?  Does a "SELECT" work?

Comment: Also, what are the values of $username, $password, $newlevel, and $realname?  Are they all set properly?

Answer (score 6):

If you have turned auto commit off, you will have to explicitly call the commit method after you execute the query.

```
$stmt->execute();
$db->commit();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check for errors at each stage of the process: When you connect, when you prepare the statement, when you bind, when you execute, and when you close. In your code, assuming the `$db` handle was properly created, the error check happens after the `->close()` call, which should succeed, so there won't be any error at that point.

Something along these lines will show where things blew up:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (username, password, level, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
echo 'prepare error: ', $db->error, PHP_EOL;
$stmt->execute();
echo 'execute error: ', $db->error
etc....
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the string "Any Errors" is being printed. If not, then the statement:

```
if ($stmt = $db->prepare($query))
```

is returning false. You should move `echo 'Any Errors: '.$db->error.PHP_EOL;` outside of the conditional block.

Answer (score 1):

Do u initialize the values of $username, $password, $newlevel, $realname before the 
$stmt -> execute(); statement. Otherwise you have to initialize and try

Comment: Documentation on PHP's site disagrees with you. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (username, password, level, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'; 
if($stmt = $db -> prepare($query)){

     $stmt -> bind_param('ssis', $username, $password, $newlevel, $realname);

    $username='testname';$password='testpwd';$level=5;$realname='testrealname';

         $stmt -> execute(); echo "inserted SuccessFully";  $stmt -> close(); } 
else { printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);}
```

try this code. If the query is executed successfully it show the "Inserted Successfully" otherwise it shows the error.