# PHP MySQLi INSERT not working, no errors

Tags: php, mysqli

Different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677575/php-mysqli-insert-not-working-but-not-giving-any-errors), but similar in that I don't get an error when adding information to my database.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'nlcc_ver1'.'tUsers' ('userID', 'userName', 'userPassword', 'userHash',
'user_first_name', 'user_last_name', 'user_corps', 'is_admin', 'is_trg', 'is_sup', 'is_co')
VALUES (NULL, '" . $userName . "', '" . $hash . "', '" . $salt . "', '" . $f_name . "', '" .
$l_name . "', '" . $corps . "', '" . $admin . "', '" . $trg . "', '" . $sup . "', '" . $co . "')";
$hostname_Database = "localhost";
$database_Database = "nlcc_ver1";
$username_Database = "root";
$password_Database = "";
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname_Database, $username_Database, $password_Database, $database_Database); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
$result = $mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
echo "Query run. Inserted UserID " . mysqli_insert_id($mysqli) . "<br />";
```

Line breaks inserted to avoid sideways scrolling... It says on the web page that mysqli_insert_id($mysqli) is 0, and nothing is added to the table on my database. I do not see an error connecting to the database appearing, and MySQL is running on my server, and phpinfo() shows both the MySQL and MySQLI extension loaded. This is just a development machine, so don't worry about the security (i.e. no password). I have tried googling the problem, but am not finding too much. I don't know about object oriented PHP programming with ->, I am used to using _. Is this method still supported?

Comment: Shouldn't you do the INSERT after the connection ?

Comment: How do you know that there are no errors? You never actually checked for any with the query.

Comment: @Tomalak: I have the database open in Navicat, and hit the Refresh button. It doesn't change

Comment: @CJBarone: Huh? What doesn't change? The fact that you're still not doing any error checking on your query doesn't change.

Comment: @Tomalak What type of error checking should I do? I have debugging echos every couple of lines that output what SHOULD appear, and I have Navicat open showing me my tables

Comment: @CJBarone: You did zero checks on `$result`. My answer shows how to check for errors with the query.

Comment: Lots of answers have `if(!$result)` which is not correct as `0` == `false` is true because type isn't also compared. Proper test for error is `if(false===$result){ /* error */ }`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've mixed procedural and object-oriented MySQLi styles. This has led to you trying to use the functions like `mysqli_query($mysqli)` instead of the member functions like `$mysqli->query()`. Your `$mysqli` is an *object*, not a resource handle.

And, you're not performing any error checking on your query. If you were, you'd see that you have mistakenly used single quotes to delimit table and field names, not backticks.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `nlcc_ver1`.`tUsers`
       (`userID`, `userName`, `userPassword`, `userHash`,
        `user_first_name`, `user_last_name`, `user_corps`,
        `is_admin`, `is_trg`, `is_sup`, `is_co`)
       VALUES (NULL, '" . $userName . "', '" . $hash . "', '" . $salt . "', '" .
               $f_name . "', '" . $l_name . "', '" . $corps . "', '" . $admin .
               "', '" . $trg . "', '" . $sup . "', '" . $co . "')";

$hostname_Database = "localhost";
$database_Database = "nlcc_ver1";
$username_Database = "root";
$password_Database = "";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname_Database, $username_Database, $password_Database, $database_Database); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
   printf("%s\n", $mysqli->error);
   exit();
}

echo "Query run. Inserted UserID " . $mysqli->insert_id . "<br />";
```

I strongly suggest using [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) as your reference. It's quite clear on how to use these functions when you're using either procedural or object-oriented style MySQLi.

Comment: This worked! You forgot an apostrophe being changed after userName, and I can't edit it yet. Thank you though :)

Comment: Really? Where? Glad you got it working; do you understand the reasoning?

Comment: Not completely, but I'm reading a PDF to learn OOP. Last time I used PHP/MySQLi was version 4 a couple years ago. I guess this one changed

Comment: @CJBarone: You should get yourself a decent, up-to-date PHP book, not some PDF written by a spotty teenager in a basement! :)

Comment: Can do... Any recommendations? I had a book called PHP and MySQL Programming: Second Edition, but like I said, that was a few years ago and taught procedural programming, not OOP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249835/book-recommendation-for-learning-good-php-oop

Comment: Note that successful `INSERT` returns 0, so `(!result)` does not behave properly. Instead  `if( false===$result)` will be "true" when there is an error.

Comment: @ChrisK: [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) says: _"Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE."_ Is it wrong?

Comment: @lightness I commented based on the behavior of an INSERT in a fresh php7 install going into production...

Comment: @ChrisK: Can you present a testcase? That would be very strange and unexpected behaviour, which does not match that described by the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

```
$mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

should be

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

OR

```
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

AND later on

```
$mysqli->insert_id();
```

Comment: No. He's not using procedural style (not consistently, at least).

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
'nlcc_ver1'.'tUsers'
```

You have to use backticks here as quote character:

```
`nlcc_ver1`.`tUsers`
```

But however(assuming that the $ in $mysqli_query is just a typo): You will not get errors for the query , unless you use mysqli_error() right after executing the query.

Comment: I've never used backticks before... All the other PHP sites I made (I haven't used PHP for a couple years) were all using " and '. I downloaded a PDF on OOP in PHP, maybe that'll explain it more

Comment: It's not required to quote identifiers like table-names, but when you decide to do it the only quote-character is the backtick.

Answer (score 0):

SET AutoCommit = 1 before inserting

```
$mysqli->query('SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this project is long dead now. Thanks for offering your help though!