# Php INSERT INTO request failing silently

Tags: php, mysql, insert

My code is as follows:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO favorites (id, profile_id, item_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
        if ($stmt)
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $maxID, $provider, $ID);
            if(!$stmt->execute())
            {
                echo ("Error" . $this->db->error);
                return $this->db->error;
            }
            else
            {
                echo("success");
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else 
        {
            echo ("Error" . $this->db->error);
            return $this->db->error;
        }
```

Despite my best efforts, this prepared statement is not doing anything. When I type the values directly into MYSQL prompt, it works properly. However, when I run this script, it does nothing.

Notes: $maxID, $provider, $ID are all valid values to insert. It throws no errors on the script or on the server error log. I'm very confused about why it does not add a row. Is there a glaring mistake in my code?

Thanks!!

EDIT: Added up new code, same thing. Execute is passing as well.

Comment: $stmt is object. So, it always would be true.

Comment: change `$stmt->execute();` to `$stmt->execute() or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: Edited post, your suggestions didn't work. Also sectus do your research before you post, $stmt won't be an object if the prepare statement fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP mysqli Insert not working, but not giving any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677575/php-mysqli-insert-not-working-but-not-giving-any-errors/11883937#11883937)

Turned out that this was my solution. ^ Autocommit was off.

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT` isn't failing silently - you're just not looking for the error. You're checking the return status of your `prepare` call, but not that of the `execute` call. Try this:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $maxID, $provider, $ID);
$stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I edited my code - it still throws no errors. What is going on?

Comment: Honestly don't know. Your code still has an error: the error message comes back from a prepared statement in `$stmt->error`. This isn't the problem here, since it should still give a message, albeit possibly the wrong or incomplete one. Have you checked the server error logs - there might be something there that'll give you a clue.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the question that I have checked server logs. Nothing wrong there. And I think it doesn't matter as much the syntax because the string "success" is printing... It isn't even throwing any error at all.